# Azure functions with service bus trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

We have a azure functions with service bus trigger with session enabled. We are trying to process a collection of messages belonging to one sessionId. What we observe is that function receive only single message at a time. Any way to let the azure function to receive collection of messages belonging to a session for every say 5 mins

```
public async Task Run(
 [ServiceBusTrigger("<<topicname>>","<<subscriptionname>>", Connection = "<<connectionname>>", IsSessionsEnabled = true, IsBatched = true)]
 ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> userProperties, string sessionId)
```

The function trigger gets executed the moment topic receives a message which means there will be always a single message is delivered to the function. In this case What does the arg IsBatched do? does it make the function to wait for some time so that topic receives multiple messages.

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried?

Comment: Post updated with code snippet

Comment: is it a in-process or isolated function?

Comment: its dotnet-isolated

Comment: Can you please share your complete function code

Comment: I resolved it. It was the nuget version package that i was using was not supported for batch enabled. After updating the package, i am getting the message collection.  Thanks